# How to make TeXForm use TemplateBox to generate code?

Tags: output-formatting, latex, boxes, templates

If I define the `TraditionalForm` formatting of `myFunction` without `TemplateBox`, then 
[`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) works properly:

```
ClearAll[myFunction]
myFunction /: HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[myFunction[a_, b_, c_], TraditionalForm]] := 
  SubsuperscriptBox[ToBoxes[a], ToBoxes[b], ToBoxes[c]]


myFunction[h, 1, 2] // TeXForm
(* h_1^2 *)
```

But if I try to define it using `TemplateBox`,

```
ClearAll[myFunction]
myFunction /: HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[myFunction[a_, b_, c_], TraditionalForm]] := 
  TemplateBox[
    {ToBoxes[a], ToBoxes[b], ToBoxes[c]}, "myFunctionTag", 
    DisplayFunction :> (SubsuperscriptBox[#1, #2, #3] &)
  ];
```

`TraditionalForm` works correctly,

```
myFunction[h, 1, 2] // TraditionalForm
```

`(*`  $h_1^2$ `*)`

but `TeXForm` does not return code to format the expression as in `TraditionalForm`:

```
myFunction[h, 1, 2] // TeXForm
(* \text{myFunctionTag}[h,1,2] *)
```

Instead, it is just replacing the head of the function with the *tag* of `TemplateBox`.  What is the correct way to make `TeXForm` generate code out of a `TemplateBox`?  I'm looking for a solution that can be programmed into a package.

Comment: Try using `Rule` instead of `RuleDelayed` in your `TemplateBox` definition.

Comment: [D'oh!](https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/theprojectterra/images/1/1a/D%27oh.gif/revision/latest?cb=20120806064936) Voting to close.

Comment: The docs indicate that `RuleDelayed` is acceptable in a `TemplateBox`, so I don't think it's a bad question

Comment: @CarlWoll Please write an answer to this question, so I can accept.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but note that using `ToBoxes` instead of `MakeBoxes`, on RHS, introduces evaluation leaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal function used by [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) to process boxes is `` System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes ``. This function is expecting the [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction) option of a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) to use [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule), not [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed). Compare:

```
System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes @ TemplateBox[
    {"a"},
    "FOO",
    DisplayFunction :> (#&)
]

System`Convert`CommonDump`ExpandTemplateBoxes @ TemplateBox[
    {"a"}, 
    "FOO", 
    DisplayFunction -> (#&)
]
```

> RowBox[{"FOO", "[", RowBox[{"a"}], "]"}]
>
> "a"

When [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed) is used, the box structure generated by the [`DisplayFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction) is ignored. So, modify your [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) format to use [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule):

```
ClearAll[myFunction]
myFunction /: MakeBoxes[myFunction[a_, b_, c_], TraditionalForm] := 
    TemplateBox[
        {ToBoxes[a], ToBoxes[b], ToBoxes[c]}, "myFunctionTag", 
        DisplayFunction -> (SubsuperscriptBox[#1, #2, #3] &)
    ]

myFunction[h, 1, 2] // TeXForm
```

> h_1^2

Note that I removed a superfluous [`HoldPattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldPattern) in your definition.

Comment: Could you forward this issue somewhere? That is either is should accept RuleDelayed or the documentation of TemplateBox should stress that out. Currently the second example uses RuleDelayed for the DisplayFunction.