# Bug with TeXForm conversion of superscript in strings

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, latex, boxes

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

Consider a String expression with a [`TemplateBox`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox.html) superscript:

```
expr = "\!\(\*TemplateBox[{\"base\",\"super\"},\n\"Superscript\"]\)"
```

In *Mathematica* 10.1 this produces errors when [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) is applied:

```
TeXForm[expr]
```

> \$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 4096 exceeded during
>   evaluation of
>   Message[Message::msgl,Hold[{\$RecursionLimit::reclim2,\$RecursionLimit::reclim2,$RecursionLimit::reclim2,General::stop}]]. >>
>
> \$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 4096 exceeded during
>   evaluation of {\$RecursionLimit::reclim2}. >>
>
> \$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 4096 exceeded during
>   evaluation of {OutputStream[Name: stdout Unique ID: 1]}. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of \$RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be
>   suppressed during this calculation. >>

How can this be patched?

---

A related question, but not dealing with Strings:

- [How to make TeXForm use TemplateBox to generate code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/152656/121)

Comment: Reproduced in the latest version. Did you report to WRI already?

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks.  No, I did not; feel free to do it yourself if you are so inclined.

Comment: @Szabolcs I found a duplicate.